# Can HTML5 & CSS3 be used with C#6.0?

Tags: c#, android, ios, css, html

I am new to software development (literally started in December 2015 - I'm from a scientific background but have a few ideas I want to develop regarding mobile/web/universal apps for apple, google and microsoft OS'). I have learnt C# 6.0, JS, HTML5 and CSS3 and have had previous experience with python and java in the past (java was literally just updating some user content for a training site; python was for my grad dissertation involving creating wild-type (ie naturally-occuring) & mutant human receptors, their structure, how they respond to drugs / chemicals via python-based simulation software; and how they compare to lab data).

I prefer using C# 6.0 but am ambivalent about using JS for backend. What are the pros and cons of using C# vs JS for cross-platform development (particularly if you want to incorporate native features such as camera or biometric scanners). Also what are the pros and cons of node.js vs angular.js? As it stands, I have the latest versions of xamarin and cordova installed on my PC. (ps the C# vs JS is for cross-platform development as I hate using java and dont have access to a mac).

for server backend for web-app, im probably sticking with C# or maybe learning c++ / ruby on rails.

I also plan on using a DB and want to know if mongoDB can be used with MySQL (if so, what resources would be useful to learning mongo and can mongo be implemented on visual studio 2015).

thanks (ps I dont mind if there are multiple answers: the more people explain, the better I can learn and understand things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser can only execute HTML/CSS/JavaScript. So all code that can run on the client side in the browser must use JavaScript.

What the server backend is written in is of no concern to the browser. Web development frameworks definitely exist for Java, C#, Ruby (Rails), PHP, JavaScript (Node.js), etc.

When you look to cross platform app development tools Xamarin is nice because it can create code for pretty much any platform using C#. You can also use HTML/CSS/JavaScript with toolkits like Apache Cordova and Windows (Mobile) also allows you to write whole Apps using HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

As for your question on using HTML/CSS with C# as a programming language - to my knowledge that's not really a supported scenario. You can call into C# code from JavaScript in Windows Universal Apps but that's pretty much the extent of it.